# How to specify the QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory() method?

Tags: c++, qt, directory, qfiledialog

With the method/command:

```
OpenCreateDirectory() 
{  
    QString Directory = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this,
                        tr("Choose Or Create Directory"),
                        "/home",
                        QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
}
```

I can create a new directory or choose an existing one. Is there a way to disable the possibility to create a new directory? Also, is there a way to disable the possibility to choose an existing directory?

To be more precise: When I use the method above, a window pops up in which I can create a new directory OR open an existing directory. What I want to do is to limit the method, so that I just can create a new directory without being able to just open an existing directory OR in the other case limit the method, so that I just can open an existing directory without being able to create a new directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prevent the creation of a new directory by using these options:

```
QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog | QFileDialog::ReadOnly 
| QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly
```

The options `ReadOnly` doesn't have any effect if you use native dialogs, at least on Windows.

---

And for disabling the choice of an already existing directory, you can't. 

But you could either add the name of the directory to be created as a separate option, or check that the chosen directory is not empty.

Comment: This works fine. I just left the "| QFileDialog::ReadOnly 
| QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly" out of it, because these arguments are not necessary. I accept this answer. greetings

Comment: Well if going non-native you might wish to create a manual file dialog screen? and use `setFileMode()`

Comment: @Streight According to QFileDialog source code, ReadOnly is necessary to disable the "newFolderButton" and on Windows the button is enabled without that option.

Comment: Unfortunately "QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog" is required. Otherwise the button "New Directory" will still be visible. However, dont using the native dialog looks ugly on my OS.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can add the options `QFileDialog::ReadOnly` when you create your `QFileDialog`.
So create it with :

```
QString Directory = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Choose Or Create Directory"),
                                                         "/home",
                                                           QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks | QFileDialog::ReadOnly);
```

The "Create Directory" button of the file dialog still exists, but you can't create the directory. I successfully used this feature on Ubuntu.

Comment: Unfortunatly does not work. I added "| QFileDialog::ReadOnly", but I still can create a new directory with the method, I also run it on Ubuntu, the create button still exists and I can use it :D.

Comment: That is very strange... When I click on the button, i am able to set a name to a new folder, but when I click on enter (to finalize the folder creation) i have an error message wich said : "Error creating directory: Permission denied"...